# To set system-wide preferences in firefox: Should I use syspref.js or local-settings.js?

Tags: firefox

There are (at least) two config files that seem to be made to define organizational preferences that should be valid for all users of firefox on a machine: `syspref.js` and `local-settings.js`. Additionally, [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences) talks about using ´all-companyname.js´.

It tried to define locked preferences by using ´lockPref´ in ´syspref.js´ as [described here](http://terokarvinen.com/2016/firefox-system-wide-settings-etcfirefoxsyspref-js) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Firefox/Einstellungen_Sperren/). However, then firefox complains about an unknown keyword. However, I can define the [´general.config.filename´](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences) in both ´syspref.js´ or ´local-settings.js´.

And in addition, one can also define group policies, e.g. using the [´policies.json´](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates).

So, my question is: Which of these possibilities should I use for which purpuse? Is there a good and up-to-date documentation that explains this?

Thanks!

Comment: All instructions are provided here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox-enterprise/deploy-firefox-for-enterprise

Comment: Thanks you for your hint. I previously had a look at this site and found information about policies.json there. However, I didn't find an answer to my question about the different config files and when to use which.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in the latest Firefox versions,
you should now use `pref("...","...",locked);` instead of `lockPref("...","...");`.

Example :

```
pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://...", locked);
```

see https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js/issues/415#issuecomment-419739194

> firefox-esr (60.0esr-1) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> - The use of `lockPref` in preferences under /etc/firefox-esr is
>     deprecated.
>     Please use `pref("name", value, locked)` instead. `lockPref` will still
>     be supported for compatibility purpose until version 67.
>
>   -- Mike Hommey   Thu, 10 May 2018 09:36:46 +0900

Comment: Interesting ... Can you point be at documentation about this?

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js/issues/415#issuecomment-419739194).

Comment: Thx! Did they also mention somewhere *why* they did change the API .......?

Comment: Apparently it's just streamlining of the interface.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (tick the V sign). See [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for an explanation of why this is important.

Comment: Well, it was definitively helpful, but didn't answer the original question when & for what I should use all the different config files and customization options. I really would like to understand this.

Comment: The documentation doesn't yet exist. As you can see, the information is still only found in answers to posts in a very partial manner. It's too early yet.

Comment: hm, change the API in a breaking way and doesn't inform users ... well ...?

Comment: I just tried this with FF 69 on linux mint: using lockPref in mozilla.cfg works, while pref(.., locked) produces an "locked not defined" error. So, now I'm confused.

Comment: Some repositories might be behind the latest version. No fun [living in changing times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_you_live_in_interesting_times).

Answer (score 1):

Reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment_before_60 I got the impression that *all* files in the "prefs" directory are read. It says:

> Create a JavaScript file that instructs to use a administrative config
>   file at startup. For best results, the filename should be early in the
>   alphabet, for example; 00_admin-prefs.js By convention this file is
>   named autoconfig.js, but other filenames will work.

So, this suggests, that the file is often named `autoconfig.js`.

On Linux Mint, there is a sym link from `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/syspref.js` to `/etc/firefox/syspref.js`. So I assume that for this distro that's the place to go.

The doc above states that pref dir can be found:

Linux: `browser/defaults/preferences`
Windows: `defaults\pref`
Mac: `Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/defaults/pref`